# Alien::wxWidgets install fails on OSX 10

Tags: macos, perl, cpan, wxwidgets

It's basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689670/alienwxwidgets-install-fails-on-osx10-10) which didn't really ended up.

I'm facing the same issue and I went a bit further. I had to change the code to allow a newer Macos sdk (10.11). So it compiled for a while but then failed whith this:

```
❯❯❯ perl build
Building Alien-wxWidgets
/Users/guiohm/.cpan/build/Alien-wxWidgets-0.67-rVjMTK/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/bk-deps clang -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -c -o wxtiff_tif_lzma.o -DNDEBUG  -I../src/jpeg -I/Users/guiohm/.cpan/build/Alien-wxWidgets-0.67-rVjMTK/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/src/tiff/libtiff -I../src/tiff/libtiff -dynamic -fPIC -DPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/Users/guiohm/.cpan/build/Alien-wxWidgets-0.67-rVjMTK/wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/lib/wx/include/osx_cocoa-unicode-3.0 -I../include -Wall -Wundef -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common  ../src/tiff/libtiff/tif_lzma.c
../src/tiff/libtiff/tif_lzma.c:38:10: fatal error: 'lzma.h' file not found
#include "lzma.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [wxtiff_tif_lzma.o] Error 1
system: make all: 512 at build line 68.

❯❯❯ brew search
lzma is now part of the xz formula.

❯❯❯ brew info
xz: stable 5.2.2 (bottled)
General-purpose data compression with high compression ratio
http://tukaani.org/xz/
/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2 (91 files, 1.4M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/xz.rb
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary

❯❯❯ brew install xz
Warning: xz-5.2.2 already installed

❯❯❯ find / -name "lzma.h"
/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2/include/lzma.h
/usr/local/include/lzma.h

❯❯❯ ll /usr/local/include/lzm*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 guiohm admin 31 Oct 11 15:58 /usr/local/include/lzma -> ../Cellar/xz/5.2.2/include/lzma
lrwxr-xr-x 1 guiohm admin 33 Oct 11 15:58 /usr/local/include/lzma.h -> ../Cellar/xz/5.2.2/include/lzma.h
```

The weird thing is when I checked the config logs:
This one (`./wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/src/tiff/config.log`) has other errors than lzma, for instance:

```
configure:18047: checking for lzma_code in -llzma
configure:18072: clang -o conftest -g -O2 -Wall -W  -stdlib=libc++ conftest.c -llzma  -ljpeg -lz  >&5
configure:18072: $? = 0
configure:18081: result: yes
configure:18096: checking lzma.h usability
configure:18096: clang -c -g -O2 -Wall -W  conftest.c >&5
configure:18096: $? = 0
configure:18096: result: yes
configure:18096: checking lzma.h presence
configure:18096: clang -E  conftest.c
configure:18096: $? = 0
configure:18096: result: yes
configure:18096: checking for lzma.h
configure:18096: result: yes
configure:18199: checking for X
configure:18307: clang -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:89:10: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
configure:18307: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "LibTIFF Software"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tiff"
```

[See the full version](http://pastebin.com/raw/qwNLm8GF).

Ans it's more or less the same with `./wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/config.log`.

When I changed the code to allow os10.10 SDK, it was previously expecting up to 10.8 or maybe 10.9. I suppose the whole issue comes now from this.
Should I try to fetch an old MacOS SDK?

Basically, I just want to compile Slic3r --gui from source, which requires Wx, which requires wxwidgets.

Comment: And here is the full `./wxWidgets-3.0.2/bld/config.log`: http://pastebin.com/raw/6d3zBSbj

Comment: weird, can you try to compile wxWidgets by hand, i.e. without automation? Just do ../configure && make && make install.

Comment: `brew uninstall xz` fixed it for me. source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1285317

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that libtiff configure detects `lzma.h` under `/usr/local` because it doesn't use `-isysroot`, but its compilation does, because of the SDK option, and fails to find it. The right thing to do would be to use `-I/usr/local/include` explicitly in wxWidgets configure, but for now you should be able to work around this by doing `export CPATH=/usr/local/include LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` to bypass it.

Alternatively (and IMHO preferably), do `brew install tiff jpeg png` (not sure that the formulae names are correct, please check them) to avoid building the builtin versions of these libraries in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Running `brew install xz` fixed the issue for me.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37594849/6381715